# Rota não funcionando com ui-router - AngularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Tenho a rota /main, que quando solicitada redireciona para uma página html. A url fica correta, mas não está carregando nada, permanece na página de login.

Essa rota é acessada quando o usuário realiza o login no sistema, no caso é a página inicial após o login.

Queria entender porque não funciona....

Meu codigo é este:

```
 /* Configuração de rotas */
 app.config(function($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.when('/main', {
      templateUrl : 'views/public/main.html'
    })
 });
```

Na página main.html, tem a div com a ng-view e os arquivos javascript necessários sendo importados.

```
 <div ng-view></div>
```

O back-end java é o responsável por fazer o redirect para a página main, após o login ser realizado.

Segue código java:

```
    private String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException{

    String context = request.getServletContext().getContextPath();
    User user = new UserDAO().doLogin(request.getParameter("mail"), request.getParameter("password"));
    JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
    try {
        HttpSession sessao = request.getSession();
        if (user != null) {             
            sessao.setAttribute("user", user);
            response.sendRedirect(context + "/main");
        } else {
            msg.put("msg", "Erro ao logar");
            sessao.setAttribute("msg", "Usuario ou senha invalido!");
            response.sendRedirect(context + "/index.html?login=invalid");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msg.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Com o Ui-Router você deve usar a diretiva dele para fazer o roteamento e não a diretiva padrão do NgRoute.

Invés de:

```
<div ng-view></div> ou <ng-view></ng-view>
```

Você deve usar:

```
<div ui-view></div> ou <ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: Giovane tentei aqui cara e não deu certo mesmo assim. A url ficou assim:

http://localhost:8080/odonto/#!/main

E não aconteceu nada, ficou na página de login.